# Shifting on the X-axis while reprojecting Gauss-Krüger zone 3 to UTM zone 33N

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, germany

I'm having trouble converting geodata from [Gauss-Krüger Zone 3](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/dhdn-gauss-kruger-zone-3/) to [UTM 33N](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/25833/).
See attached image.

I don't know why, but there seems to be a shift on the X-axis. I found a similar  question here but am not sure how to do this in QGIS:
https://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/discussion/790705/thread/a824273a/?limit=25#567a

[image: example]

The left map is from here: https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html

The right map is from here: https://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/grids_germany/multi_annual/precipitation/

Comment: could you add some background to those maps so we can see the shift?

Comment: Yes, I added this information above

Comment: It looks like you might have reassigned the projection instead of actually converting it. Make sure to use the "Save as" function on your layer and specify your new projection there. Don't use the "Set layer crs" function.

Comment: No that wasn't the solution. Still the same shift.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to first set the Layer to EPSG:31467 and then export it as UTM33N.